# Easy way to allow the user to select from several predefined colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, color-picker

I'm creating an ASP.NET website that uses [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) for styling.

I'm looking for the simplest way to allow the user to select from a predefined list of colors. I would prefer a dropdown, and that the colors be visible as opposed to selecting the color names. Also, I'd like a simple approach with the smallest possible number of dependencies.

It looks like Bootstrap has a color picker, but it allows/requires the user to create any random color. I need the selection to be limited to several predefined colors.

I'm looking for recommendations and experiences with available options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are already using Boostrap, here is a possible implementation:

```js
(function() {
  const _init = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.customColorPicker').forEach(picker => {
      //create a button group
      const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
      wrapper.classList.add("btn-group");
      //add toggle button
      const button = document.createElement("button");
      const colorPreviewBox = document.createElement("div");
      colorPreviewBox.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
      colorPreviewBox.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block; height:100%; width:2em; margin-right:6px; border: 1px solid #888");
      button.textContent = "Choose Color";
      button.classList.add("btn");
      button.classList.add("btn-default");
      button.classList.add("dropdown-toggle");
      button.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
      button.prepend(colorPreviewBox);
      wrapper.appendChild(button);

      //add options
      const menuDiv = document.createElement("div");
      menuDiv.classList.add("dropdown-menu");
      const options = [];
      for (let i = 0, n = picker.options.length; i < n; i++) {
        options.push(picker.options[i]);
      }
      options.forEach(option => {
        const optionLink = document.createElement("a");
        optionLink.classList.add("dropdown-item");
        optionLink.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        optionLink.style.background = option.text;
        optionLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const color = option.text;
          picker.value = option.text;
          colorPreviewBox.style.background = option.text;
        });
        menuDiv.appendChild(optionLink);
      });
      wrapper.appendChild(menuDiv);
      picker.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, picker.nextSibling);
      picker.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    });
  };

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _init);

})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select class="customColorPicker">
  <option>#000</option>
  <option>#f00</option>
  <option>#ff0</option>
  <option>#0f0</option>
  <option>#0ff</option>
  <option>#00f</option>
  <option>#f0f</option>
  <option>#fff</option>
</select>
```

Important Points:

1. All you have to do us add a `class="customColorPicker"` to an `select`, then add the colors you want as options like this `<option>#0f0</option>`. You can give the select a name or ID which you can use to retrieve the value that the user has selected.
2. An IIFE takes care of everything. In this implementation init runs only once, when the page loads. If you are going to be adding pickers dynamically to the page or using a framework that does that like React or Angular, then you would also need to implement a method to "refresh" or transform the newly inserted input boxes
3. Bootstrap-select could also be an alternative. See: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/.

Comment: Can you tell me what all those scripts are in your last code block? I see Bootstrap, which I already have. Obviously, I also have jQuery as well. Which ones do I need to add?

Comment: `bootstrap.min.css` the bootstrap stylesheet and `bootstrap.min.js` is the Bootstrap script.  The other two, `jQuery` and `popper.min.js` are both required by Bootstrap. This information can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I explained in the comment you're responding to that I already have Bootstrap and jQuery. So when I ask which ones I need, those are not the ones.

Comment: The use of `popper.min.js` as well as the other scripts is explained right there